# Создание модифицированного SystemUI.apk

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Хочу модифицировать `SystemUI.apk`. Прошивка CyanogenMod13. Нужно добавить свой код в случае неверного ввода кода разблокировки графического ключа, а именно, запуск Shell скрипта с уже рабочим функционалом. На гитхабе я уже нашел куда писать, сам запуск скрипта уже проверил на тестовом приложении. Скачал исходники `android_frameworks_base` из ветки `cm13` репозитория `LineageOS`. Ресурсы бегло проверил с родным `SystemUI.apk` - все совпадает. Создал проект, закинул все ресурсы, скопировал все исходники из `com.android.proguard`, `com.android.systemui` и `com.android.settingslib`. Было просто море ошибок, недостающие классы были указаны в импортах, это были классы из пакетов SDK. Я скопировал также всю папку `android` со всеми исходниками из скачанного архива. Сейчас в проекте около 10 тысяч ошибок, все импорты классов с разрешением `.aidl` имеют ошибки. Есть даже методы, которые по идее должны быть, но их нет, непонятные ошибки. Студия просто берет и зависает иногда! Скажите, что мне делать, разбираться в ошибках дальше или есть другой способ модификации системных приложений? Спасибо

Comment: Честно, опыт у меня маленький, но я использовал apktool брал готовое, перегонял в smali дописывал пару строк и собирал обратно. Мне кажется это проще при малых разовых правках.

Comment: @pavel, при декомпиляции часть классов пропадает, компиляция потом оканчивается сломанным apk

Comment: @Flippy надо понять почему часть классов пропадает - такого не должно быть... Вам скорее всего лучше самому собирать прошивку целиком. но если хотите содифицировать как сказал pavel, то все должно получиться... Киньте ссылочку на репозиторий =)

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, все таки получилось!!! В апктул :) в smali коде нашел место где была реакция на неверный ключ и вставил свой код декомпилированный в smali ;) собрал apk потом декомпилировал его в http://javadecompilers.com/apk убедился в java коде что все верно, сунул META-INF оригинала и подменил системный SystemUI с правами буквой Г. Запуск скрипта работает! Мало того, я еще добавил скрытую запись звука и ее тоже вместе с фото отправляю себе в вк :)